# Can't get simple if / else statement to work

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

I am searching a table in my `DB` to return a tick if a name matches a `$_GET['name']` variable that I have passed in the URL.

I want a tick displayed if the name exists and a cross if it does not.

The purpose is to populate a rota / timetable of availability.

**The code I have so far;**

```
<?php foreach($rota_sun as $rota_sunday): ?>
       <?php if(strpos($rota_sunday['person_name'], $_GET['name']) !== false) { ?>
              <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <?php } ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**My code for the query is;**

```
$query = "SELECT
                rota_sunday.id AS rota_id,
                rota_sunday.person_id,
                rota_sunday.person_name
            FROM rota_sunday WHERE rota_sunday.person_name = '$_GET['$name']'
        "; 
    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $rota_sun = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**My table contains three rows;**

1. id
2. person_id
3. person_name

The array I'm using is;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rota_id] => 16
            [person_id] => 0
            [person_name] => Gina
        )

)
```

You'll see that Gina exists - so if `?name=Gina` is in my URL a tick should be shown but `?name=Fred` or `?name=John` etc is in my URL a cross should be displayed.

**Issue:** The tick is displaying when the name exists but the cross isn't displaying when the name doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the current problem? Does it always enter in if or else?

Comment: have you checked the values of $rota_sunday['person_name'] and $_GET['name']? You should check for white spaces and also the cases.

Comment: The tick is displaying when the name exists but the cross isn't displaying when the name doesn't exist.

Comment: @Anant thats what I want - to mtch name exactly and display a tick if true. No match display a cross.

Comment: @Anant I have added it to my original question - You'll see that Gina exists - so if `?name=Gina` is in my URL a tick should be shown but `?name=Fred` or `?name=John` etc is in my URL a cross should be displayed.

Comment: @Ben  which font-awesom library you used?

Comment: @Anant the latest - I've checked those icons are working and they are.

Comment: @Ben  i used it and it's working. I have given answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of errors
  ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those if any happen
  $_GET['name'] = 'fiksun';
  $rota_sun = Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            'rota_id' => 16,
            'person_id' => 0,
            'person_name' => 'Gina'
        ),
    '1' => Array
        (
            'rota_id' => 16,
            'person_id' => 0,
            'person_name' => 'fiksun'
        )

)
?>
<?php foreach($rota_sun as $rota_sunday): ?>
    <?php if($rota_sunday['person_name']== $_GET['name']) { ?>
        <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $rota_sunday['person_name'];?></span>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $rota_sunday['person_name'];?></span>
  <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/cf4ecd

Note:- download font-awesome library from here:- http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Put the complete folder in your current working directory

Add the css file correctly.

this is working directory structure:- http://prntscr.com/cf4fuk

Change your query:-

```
$query = "SELECT rota_sunday.id AS rota_id, rota_sunday.person_id AS person_id, rota_sunday.person_name AS person_name FROM rota_sunday WHERE rota_sunday.person_name Like '%".$_GET['$name']."%'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I think I found the cause of the issue by using your example - still can't fix it though - my array seems to only be returning one result from the DB. `Array ( [rota_id] => 17 [person_id] => 0 [person_name] => Gina )` despite there being two records.

Comment: It is getting 1 result because of your query.

Comment: @Ben  check the query i have given in my answer. use it and check

Comment: @Anant thank you - the query is indeed working but its returning all records in one box - just needs to be a tick or a cross - http://prntscr.com/cf4pgn

Comment: @Anant it works when I change `$_GET['$escort']` to `$_GET['name']` - thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Anant still not getting the cross though.

Answer (score 0):

This query will select just one person from DB.

```
$query = "SELECT
            rota_sunday.id AS rota_id,
            rota_sunday.person_id,
            rota_sunday.person_name
        FROM rota_sunday WHERE rota_sunday.person_name = " . $_GET['name'] . "LIMIT 1"; 
try 
{ 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$rota_sun = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If this person exist then $rota_sun will contain result if not then this will return false and you will get the red cross.

```
   <?php if($rota_sun) { ?>
          <span style="color:green; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   <?php } else { ?>
          <span style="color:red; font-size:22px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That's what I am doing but using an if / else statement to show one thing if matched and something ese if it's not. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: The problem isn't with my query - that is working fine and is storing values as an array. I can see them in the dump. The issue is displaying a cross if the name can't be matched in my DB table.

Comment: Do you need to display all the person name or just one of it?

Comment: I need it to search through the entire table match the name - show tick if it finds one (in any row) or a cross if doesn't find a match (in any row).

Comment: So then use this selection with LIMIT 1 and just fetch, and this will return false in case it doesn't exist

Comment: but this totally clears my array - to this `Array ( )` instead of `Array ( [0] => Array ( [rota_id] => 17 [person_id] => 0 [person_name] => Gina ) [1] => Array ( [rota_id] => 18 [person_id] => 0 [person_name] => Abella ) )`

Comment: " show tick if it finds one (in any row) or a cross if doesn't find a match (in any row)." So by the end you just want to show tick or cross for some "name" then why do you need all array or to search in all array if query can make this check for you?

Comment: @Ben  check this query `$query = "SELECT rota_sunday.id AS rota_id, rota_sunday.person_id AS person_id, rota_sunday.person_name AS person_name FROM rota_sunday WHERE rota_sunday.person_name Like '%".$_GET['$name']."%'";`

Comment: Yep this query seems legit, but why $_GET['$name'] not $_GET['name'] ?

Comment: @LkPark Correct - I couldn't figure it out in a query either that would work with several profiles (ie different names)